# Can I raise baby cottontail rabbits

Tags: rabbits

An adult cottontail rabbit has been staying around my house the past couple weeks. Well, the other day we found her dead, along with 2 babies, one was unfortunately dead but the other still alive.  It ran back to a hole in the ground that we discovered to be a nest with 3 perfectly healthy looking baby bunnies.

They are walking have a full coat of fur and they are a little smaller then my hand. However their ears are not 'erect' so I was wondering how old they may be, and if with very careful care we could keep them.

I know there are risks but I will put all the effort necessary to keep them healthy! Please respond with tips or past experiences; I am trying to gather all the info I can.